# iptables does not apply any rules

Tags: iptables

Let's say I want to disable HTTP(S) on my computer.

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --destination-port 80 -j DROP
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --destination-port 443 -j DROP
```

Why can I still browse webpages after executing these commands? I have been trying out various `iptables` commands, but not a single one has shown any effect so far. (my final goal is redirecting packages for a certain port)

I tried `service iptables start`, but got the message `Failed to start iptables.service: Unit iptables.service not found.` But shouldn't iptables run by default?

`head /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` says `1`.

**edit. Ok, sorry: the error actually lies somewhere else. Please feel free to look into my [other question](https://serverfault.com/questions/803525/iptables-outgoing-redirection-ignored).**

Comment: Is ipv6 enabled?

Comment: Are you trying to block your machine from making *outbound* connections to remote machines on ports tcp/80 and tcp/443?  If so, you want to modify the `OUTPUT` chain, not the `INPUT` chain.

Comment: Are you browsing pages on the computer that you entered the iptables commands on or are you browsing a remote computer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are blocking traffic in the `INPUT` chain, which is applied to IP packets coming towards your computer. The destination port here means the port on your computer. That port is random, selected by the OS when it opens the TCP socket to the remote server port 80 / 443.

When you browse other computer, packets traverse through the `OUTPUT` chain.