# iptables outgoing redirection ignored

Tags: iptables

I want to redirect outgoing packages from my machine on port `12345` for modification to another process instead (`netsed`), which will then send them to their target.

I can drop outgoing packages using `iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 12345 -j DROP`. Thus, no more packages are being sent via `12345`.

For redirecting them to netsed, it seems I need to use NAT table and DNAT:

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 12345 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:$netsed_port
```

Is this the right approach?

Because it doesn't work: It does not stop outgoing packages from reaching their original, remote target. It should, right? Shouldn't redirecting them into a dead end equal dropping them? Also, I am not receiving any packages at netsed's port.

/ using REDIRECT does not help either: `iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 12345 -j REDIRECT --to-port $netsed_port`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The iptables rule needs to be defined **before** the first package is sent by the respective process on port `12345`. This solved my problem.

also I tried disabling the firewall `ufw disable`. Not sure how this affects iptables.

redirect and dnat actually work equally well here